# Getting object of anchor tag using getElementById

Tags: javascript, object, anchor, getelementbyid

```
anchorobject = document.getElementById('backbutton');
alert(anchorobject);

<a href="http://www.hotmail.com" id="backbutton">back</a>
```

The above code alerts the href attribute string (`http://www.hotmail.com`). Not the object itself. The file I am editing is just a local file which I want to use in some third party program in the future. First, I am coding it on my local computer. When I try to get the object of a `DIV` it works just fine.

Why can't I get the object of an anchor (`<a>`) tag in JavaScript using `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: alert(anchorobject.constructor);

Comment: See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7axbR/) for all the attributes of that anchor object.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* getting the anchor object. It's just that `alert` is a very poor debugging solution. If you alert an anchor object, it will just show you it's `href`. See [this example](http://jsbin.com/arecey/edit#javascript,html). Instead, I would recommend using Firebug or Chrome with `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 alert(anchorobject.getAttribute("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `anchorobject` is your actuall anchor object, but if you use it as a string (in your case with an `alert()`), the object's `toString()` method creates a string from the `href` tag.