# getElementById returns a hyperlink's HREF not the element itself

Tags: javascript

I need to access an `"<a>"` element's text and chage it via javascript using Interet Explorer

I am doing this

```
var element = document.getElementById("LbItem MenuCLESAAsignar");
alert(element);
var text = element.text;
var value= element.value;
```

this is my html `<a>` element

```
<a class="folderopen itemLeftCarpeta" id="LbItem MenuCLESAAsignar" href="SomeUrl"> Value to change </a>
```

**alert(element);** returns the complete url

**element.text and element.value** return "undefined"

Comment: "id" values really shouldn't contain spaces.  `<a>` DOM elements don't have a "value" property, nor "text" either.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162211/getting-object-of-anchor-tag-using-getelementbyid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerHTML`.

```
var element = document.getElementById("someid");
element.innerHTML='Value changed';
```

Also, generally, `id`s don't have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "return" just the href. You shouldn't be using `alert` for debugging. Use `console.log` and you'll see that it is logging the element itself. You could use `innerHTML` to access or change the text, but it makes more sense to use `innerText` and/or `textContent`. Check out the differences and browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent). Ditch the space in your id. That's ridiculous.

Comment: @DSG nice catch, I've been writing too much php lately :) I updated my answer.